# Custom annotations for XML

Tags: java, xml, annotations

I want to build a general package for annotations that can be used in XML. The concept is similar to defining custom annotations for Java, building a special package, in which the custom annotations are defined, and so that they can be used among different projects, just by importing the package.

Is there a way to achieve that for XML? Or it isn't needed, since every annotation is defined in an XML from its basis? So only knowing the structure of the annotation, that will be used in different XML files, and applying it per hand throughout is enough?

Comment: I was hoping to get some tips and first of all whether such an approach would be possible without going too deep into extending the XML implementation. E.g. in Java, you could do that without extending the language itself.

Comment: Here is a very good example [Writing Out a DOM as an XML File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html)

Comment: What do you want the annotations to do, and what kind of XML are you trying to add them to? The official mechanism for passing hints to specific applications is Processing Instructions...

Comment: I do not need those annotations to add any functionality to the XML files. They should be used for certain queries. The kind of XML files in which I want to add annotations would be the simple plugin.xml of a Java plugin project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An annotation could be described as attribute of an element. In XML, you'd probably put "annotations" in their own XML namespace and use attributes in that namespace for annotating elements.

An example for doing so is [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa), which is used to embed machine-readable, semantic data for example into HTML documents.

Comment: Well it looks promising. Just by taking a quick look at it, I am understanding, that the specific annotations I want to build can be declared as these RDFs in a main document once and later could be used in various places of the XML-based document, right?

Comment: RDFa _might_ fit your requirements, but it might be possible you might just want to define something on your own. Have a look at XML Schema / DTD for defining schemas (restrictions) in XML.